# Difference between assembler and assembly language

Tags: assembly, architecture, compiler-construction

I'm pretty new to computer architecture.
My understanding is,
the compiler converts high level coding language to instructions which is then translated to machine code by the assembler in assembly language.
so what exactly does the assembly language do. Why don't we just have the assembler.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The instructions produced by the compiler (in some cases, not all compilers generate assembly) are the assembly code. You can also hand-write assembly.

Comment: Assembly *language* is the input language for an assembler.  When you say *Why don't we just have the assembler*, you could just as easily ask "Why don't we just have a C compiler, what's up with all these programs written in C?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do programming language compilers first translate to assembly or directly to machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845355/do-programming-language-compilers-first-translate-to-assembly-or-directly-to-mac)

Comment: The question in your title doesn't match the question in the body of your post. Please clarify.